# jquery - multiple elements of same class on page - only want to interact with one

Tags: jquery

Alright so, tricky one here.

I have some tooltips I'm displaying with jquery, the problem is there's multiple boxes on the same page with the markup so it obviously shows the div on all the elements on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".comment-des").hover(function () { // hover over
        $(".cd-tooltip").show();
    }, function () { // hover off
       $(".cd-tooltip").hide();
    })
});
```

Some html code if it helps visualise the layout.

```
<div class="cd-tooltip">
    This article has <?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?> comments.
</div>
<div class="ed-tooltip">
    Email this article.
</div>
<div class="ld-tooltip">
    Click to get article URL.
</div>

<div class="meta-holder">
    <span class="comment-des">
        <?php comments_number('0','1','%'); ?>
    </span>             
    <span class="email-des">
        <a rel="nofollow" title="Email this page" href="mailto:?Subject=<?php the_title(); ?>&body=<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></a>
    </span>
    <span class="link-des"></span>
 </div> <!-- end div meta-holder -->
```

The problem becomes, how do I just display the tooltip next to ".comment-des" when it has no parental relationship and there's multiples of them on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each code block like the one in the question has a parent element wrapping it, it's rather easy:

```
$(".comment-des").hover(function () { // hover over
    $(this).closest('.classOfWrapper').find(".cd-tooltip").show();
}, function () { // hover off
    $(this).closest('.classOfWrapper').find(".cd-tooltip").hide();
})
```

otherwise you'll need to traverse the DOM up to the closest `meta-holder`and find the previous `cd-tooltip` like so :

```
$(".comment-des").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.meta-holder').prevUntil(".cd-tooltip").last().prev().toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GbCVL/1/)

**EDIT:**

for dynamic elements, you'll need delegated event handlers :

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.comment-des', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.meta-holder').prevUntil(".cd-tooltip").last().prev().toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');
});
```

Comment: This be absolutely perfect! Thank you.

Comment: No it doesn't, I'll add a solution for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set an ID for each DIV that contains a comment.
Why don't you use "comments_number" to count up your comments?

Then, you would have a div with its very own ID and could easily select one with

```
$('div#commentID')
```

and do your stuff!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".comment-des").hover(function () { // hover over
        var el = $(this).parent();

        while(!el.is('.cd-tooltip')) el = el.prev();

        el.show();
    }, function () { // hover off
        var el = $(this).parent();

        while(!el.is('.cd-tooltip')) el = el.prev();

        el.hide();
    })



});
```

It while select the first `.cd-tooltip` who is before the hovered element.

It can be reduced to that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $(".comment-des").hover(function () { // hover over
        var el = $(this).parent();

        while(!el.is('.cd-tooltip')) el = el.prev();

        el.toggle();
    }
});
```